# Tampermonkey: Copy source code on button press on dynamic AJAX page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tampermonkey

Trying to create a simple script that has the aim to copy the source code of a dynamic AJAX page when I press a button. The following code works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM_setClipboard
// ==/UserScript==

function doc_keyUp(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            //Left
            getHTML();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);

function getHTML() {

waitForKeyElements ("html", copyClipboard);

function copyClipboard (jNode) {
        GM_setClipboard (jNode.html());
    return true;
}
}
```

But it has one issue, waitForKeyElements is constantly active and clogging unnecessary resources as well as making the clipboard unusable. Removing "return true;" solves this, but does not help me because the page is not reloaded when I need to fetch the source code again. waitForKeyElements does not fire again in that case because the html element I am targeting stays the same, only the inner content changes.

Workflow:

1. Page accessed
2. Source Code copied
3. Page dynamically changed, but not reloaded.
4. Source Code should be copied again

Comment: This -> `document.querySelector("html").outerHTML` is all you need to get the DOM in its current state.  Any changes made to the DOM by scripts will be in that value, or is that not actually what you want?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Just get rid of the `waitForKeyElements()` and do the copy at DOM ready, and then again at button click.

Comment: I did and it is working perfectly. Thank you again, much appreciated.

Comment: No  problemo  :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using

```
document.querySelector("html").outerHTML
```

as suggested by Archer in the comments.